# How to have some text to the right of an image and some under it

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I've come across this problem: I need an image with dynamic size (25% to be exact) to have some text to the right of it and some under it.

I know that text can be put to the right of the image using `float: right`, but that makes it impossible to put any text **always under the image**.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7r51y7d4/2/

Since the image has a dynamic size, I can't just add lots of line breaks, because not only would the code be ugly, but it wouldn't work well on any device with a different screen resolution than mine.

Putting the image and the right text in a div won't help because the div will only wrap around the text, leaving the image sticking out through the div's border.

If JavaScript is needed, then so be it, however, I need a PHP-free solution. (pure HTML/CSS would be nice, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the `div` with `clear: both` CSS rule, for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.nba.net/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" width="25%">
<p>
  I want this text to be to the right of this image
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>
  I want this text to be under the image
</p>
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7r51y7d4/4/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `clear:both` to clear floating and the second text will go under the image :

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.nba.net/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" width="25%">
<p>
  I want this text to be to the right of this image
</p>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<p>
  I want this text to be under the image
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clear` property to specify that the text should be inserted after floating elements.

```
<p style="clear: both;">
    Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7r51y7d4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Target your second paragraph with CSS and use `clear:both;`

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

HTML Code:

```
<img src="http://cdn.nba.net/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" width="25%">
<p>
  I want this text to be to the right of this image
</p>
<p id="secondParagraph">
  I want this text to be under the image
</p>
```

CSS Code:

```
img {
      float: left;
      margin: 8px;
    }

#secondParagraph {
      clear:both;  
    }
```

I would also set your 25% width with CSS as well. It is best to do all styling externally with CSS, instead of in-line with HTML. Easier to manage.